# Loop over files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, operating-system

I have a series of files named `file_0001.csv`, `file_0002.csv`, ... `file_1000.csv` etc. I need to read them iteratively by creating a list of the filenames and as

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


for fileName in files:
    data = pd.read_csv("folder" + fileName)
    data = data.values
```

How do I create the list of file names by checking the first and last file.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `files = [fn for fn in os.listdir() if fn.endswith(".csv")]` maybe

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to create the specific file names, you can loop over from 1 to 1000 and create filenames

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


for i in range(1,1001):
    num = str(i)
    filename = "file_" + num.zfill(4) + ".csv"
    #data = pd.read_csv("folder" + fileName)
    #data = data.values
    print filename
```

output last 10 lines:

```
file_0991.csv
file_0992.csv
file_0993.csv
file_0994.csv
file_0995.csv
file_0996.csv
file_0997.csv
file_0998.csv
file_0999.csv
file_1000.csv
```

Comment: Thank you @arp5. Really simple but nice solution. Would it be possible to read the first and last file in order to make everything automatic?

Comment: If you don't know the exact number of files then listing the files in the folders as mentioned int th ecomments by @d.b will be better. You can directly get the filenames from directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pathlib` from the standard library. Then you can simply do

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path 

# get file number assuming the name format "file_number.csv"
def get_file_number(file_path):
    return int(file_path.stem.split("_")[1])

folder_path = Path("path/to/folder")

# sort files by file number
files = sorted(folder_path.glob("file_*.csv"), key=get_file_number)

for file in files:
    print(file.name)    # just to check 
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
    # do something with data
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the order in which the files are read is not correct

Comment: You just need to sort the files by file number first. I updated the solution to read them in the right order. Tell me if it works.